# Do I have to keep track if react has rendered to change the history?

Tags: reactjs

Based on if the user is logged to firebase or not, I have to redirect the user to the corresponding route using custom history API.
Should I keep track if react has already rendered or call render and let react handles the processs through its virtual DOM.
this is the code of the former case:

```
ReactDOM.render(<p>Loading...</p>, document.getElementById('root'))

const jsx = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
)
let hasRendered = false
const renderApp = () => {
    if(!hasRendered){
        ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('root'), () => console.log('render'))
        hasRendered = true
    }
}


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user){
        store.dispatch(login(user.uid))
        store.dispatch(startSetExpenses())
            .then(() => {
                renderApp()
                if(history.location.pathname === '/')
                    history.push('/dashboard')
            })
    }else{
        store.dispatch(logout())
        renderApp()
        history.push('/')
    }
})
```

and this is the code of the latter case:

```
ReactDOM.render(<p>Loading...</p>, document.getElementById('root'))

const jsx = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
)



firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user){
        store.dispatch(login(user.uid))
        store.dispatch(startSetExpenses())
            .then(() => {
                ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('root'))
                if(history.location.pathname === '/')
                    history.push('/dashboard')
            })
    }else{
        store.dispatch(logout())
        ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('root'))
        history.push('/')
    }
})
```

Comment: is there a reason for calling ReactDOM.render in if statements and such like that? Usually, there is a single render to root element of your App main component, and from there standard React practice is followed. see [here](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider)

Comment: yeah, I've got your point but the refactoring process is a bit tedious now. Consider this as a more general question. If you have any suggestion please fill me in.